# NoClassDefFoundError in java tester

Tags: java, class, testing, junit, heap

```
class dHeap<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements dHeapInterface<T>

public dHeap(int heapSize) {
    dVar = 2;
    size = heapSize;
    array = (T[]) new Comparable[heapSize];
    nelems = 0;

}
```

.

```
public class dHeapTester {

private dHeap<Integer> intHeap;
private dHeap<Integer> dHeap;
private dHeap<String> sHeap;


@Before
public void setUp() {

    intHeap = new dHeap<>(5);
    sHeap = new dHeap<>(5);
    dHeap = new dHeap<>(4, 5);
```

The top code is my class signature and constructor, and the bottom is my tester for it. I get a NoClassDefFoundError when running the tester and it happens during the initialization of things. Why am I getting this error? *The third initialization dHeap is using a second constructor that chooses the amount of children each node has rather than binary*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Comment: What build tool are you using.